# Styling issues in Safari

Tags: css, layout, mobile, safari, styling

I've been working on a website for a little while now, doing most of my testing in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. As I'm wrapping things up, I've tried viewing it in Safari (on Mac, iPad, and iPhone). I've noticed that certain elements are misplaced in Safari. I've tried playing with the CSS, but I've had no luck.

The page can be viewed here - http://staging.princewebdesigns.com/gallais/

See specifically the logo (being pushed down into the banner), the font of the tagline in the banner (wrapping beyond the banner and extending too far to the left), the 'Featured Work' title wrapping, the project names wrapping, and the footer wrapping.

Here is how the page should look - http://staging.princewebdesigns.com/gallais/images/chrome.png

To see how it looks on my iPhone, change the link above to .../iphone.png

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The page looks fine using Safari on Windows 7. I don't have a Mac to see if the problem is just mac based or maybe something specific to your setup. In any case, I hope that small bit of information is somewhat helpful in your diagnosis of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is (I think) that you have your browser's text zoomed in.

I loaded the page in Safari 5.1 on Mac OS 10.7.3, and it loaded fine initially. When I zoomed normally, the layout stayed intact. As soon as I tried zooming just the text, the layout broke per your description.

That being said, you may want to think hard about how to make the layout more 'flexible' in the event a user does have their text size increased. In IE, for example, the default zoom is full page zoom, but a user can still increase their text size apart from zooming. It's worth testing your layout in those situations to make sure it doesn't completely derail. I'm not saying it has to be *perfect*, but still legible.

One idea is to try out different units. I've found that when declaring horizontal lengths (e.g. margin-left) using relative measurements works, but when declaring *vertical* lengths, (e.g. margin-top) using pixel measurements works better. For super critical items, like the site logo, positon:absolute may be a good route to try.

Comment: The suggestion of absolute position for the logo worked - thanks! However, the layout of the other elements is still off on my iphone and it is not zoomed in. I uploaded a screenshot of how it looks on my iphone here - http://staging.princewebdesigns.com/gallais/images/iphone.png